# Accessing index of a v-for loop in a sibling? (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, bootstrap-4

I'm trying to produce the following (rendering div elements, broken up by a clearfix after every four elements):

```
<div class="col-md-3 form-group"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group"></div>
<div class="col-md-3 form-group"></div>
<div class="clearfix></div>
....
```

And wondering if anything as the code below is possible in VueJS or can someone help me out with an alternative?.

```
<div v-for="(sku, n) in sku_pattern" :key="n"  class="col-md-3 form-group"></div>
<div v-if="!((n+1)%4)" class="clearfix"> <!-- I know this won't work outside the scope of the previous element. -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `<template>` tag with v-for to render a block of multiple elements:

```
<template v-for="(sku, n) in sku_pattern">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group">
    </div>
    <div v-if="!((n+1)%4)" class="clearfix">
</template>
```

[Reference document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#v-for-on-a-lt-template-gt)

Comment: This is perfect, although, I encountered a small compile-time error that states the template cannot be keyed. `- <template> cannot be keyed. Place the key on real elements instead.`. Removed the key and works like a charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just in the addition of @ittus answer,

The solution to loop through siblings is the use of the `template` tag.

While, the template cannot be `keyed`, instead you have to put `key` on children's elements, like this will solve your problem.

```
<template v-for="(sku, n) in sku_pattern">
    <div class="col-md-3 form-group" :key='n'>
    </div>
    <div v-if="!((n+1)%4)" class="clearfix" :key='n'>
</template>
```

Comment: What should the key on a child element do, anyway? A key in loops is to identify the rendered item within the loop, for ordering consistency. It would not matter on child elements IMHO.